# Trouble with もう二度と列車や車には乗らん

Tags: grammar, particles, colloquial-language, manga, role-language

I've been trying to read a manga book and there's one bit that I can't get my head around. The sentence:

> もう二度{にど}と列車{れっしゃ}や車に**は**乗{の}**らん**

I'm fine with most of it but I'm confused about why the は exists and why the verb ends in らん. Please help me, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Can you double check to make sure the sentence is typed correctly?

Comment: 乗らん is short for 乗らない. 
I think は here is for emphasis but let's wait for some answers. 
And did you mean 列車??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The person is declaring that he/she will `二度と列車や車に乗らない`.

`もう`'s literal meaning is "has gotten to the state" (e.g. もう歩けない、もう食べれる), and here it indicates that the speaker has gotten to the state that he/she will never board a train or car (he/she "had enough").

The `は` specifies that he/she will **specifically** not board a train or car (while he/she might board other means of transport, like a ship or plane). It has the effect of singling out trains and cars.

`乗らん` is short for `乗らない` and shows some aggressiveness. Here it shows that he or she had enough of trains and cars and is angry enough to vow never to board them again. (e.g. saying いらん、やらん sounds much more rude/strong than いらない、やらない）

Comment: 乗らん is derived from 乗らぬ, not 乗らない.